# Splitting concatenated entries in a single column into separate rows

Tags: excel-formula

Can anyone help me with this in Excel, I need a formula to extract a correct data from this single column:

```
03127|16|D02|2|0025003128|1|D02|1|00008
03128|2|D02|1|00107
03131|3|D02|2|0020703132|1|D02|1|00000
03132|9|D02|2|0022803132|10|D02|2|00232
03131|3|D02|2|0020703132|10|D02|1|00000
03132|11|D02|2|0022803132|10|D02|2|00235
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

I want a result like this:

```
03127|16|D02|2|00250
03128|1|D02|1|00008
03128|2|D02|1|00107
03131|3|D02|2|00207
03132|1|D02|1|00000
03132|9|D02|2|00228
03132|10|D02|2|00232
03131|3|D02|2|00207
03132|10|D02|1|00000
03132|11|D02|2|00228
03132|10|D02|2|00235
```

Comment: How did you end up with such mangled data in the first place? I suspect the *real* solution would be to go back and redo whatever step caused that.

Comment: It was a flat file at first that has a ' | ' as a delimit, then i try to finish the job by placing it on excel, i tried this formula at first 
=IF(LEN(A2)>=39,LEFT(A2,20),IF(LEN(A2)=38,LEFT(A2,19),LEFT(A2,20)))

Comment: In that case, you really should use the [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) to load the data into Excel. See also [this answer on Super User](http://superuser.com/a/291454).

Comment: Yes if you have a consistent delineator symbol in your source file, the Text Import Wizard is ideal. By the time it actual enters your excel file, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the screenshot as this does not seem to match the other examples and assuming the first entry is in A1 then for longer strings this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)<25,A1,LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)+5)&"#"&MID(A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)+6,LEN(A1)))
```

should insert a hash `#` five characters after the fourth pipe `|` and merely copy the shorter strings. Copy the results into Word as text only, select all and INSERT > Tables - Table, Convert Text to Table...,  Separate text at Other: `#`, Number of columns: `1` and copy the resulting Table back in to Excel